# Workflow Foundation 4 - How to implement a partial Pre-existing ServiceContract?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

We have a pre-defined ServiceContract with 3 Operations. These 3 messages are published on MSMQ which our Workflow service (hosted in IIS) listens on.

However, our Workflow logic is interested only in 2 of the operations on which it commits the message on the Queue. Some service however posts the 3rd operation on the MSMQ, but as we are not interested in it we get a error message logged in svclog file and these messages remain on the queue.

Is there any way in which we can create a partial class and implement this 3rd operation and do nothing but just commit on the queue so that our queue does not get filled up?

Answer (score 0):

To handle this, we created a customworkflowhost and handled the UnKnownMessageReceived event in which we get the unimplemented Operations. We simply commit those to empty the queue